# How to use strings in jsp var?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to do in jsp side something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${configForm.unselectedServers}" var="item">
    String name = "";
    <c:forEach items="$item.configs" var="conf">
        name += ", " + {$conf.name}
        ....
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

`item.configs` it's an array of a class (that contains `name`). That part I know it works, I simply want to know how to put these value in a string.

---

EDIT:

I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:431)
        at java.lang.Long.<init>(Long.java:678)
        at org.apache.el.lang.ELArithmetic$LongDelegate.coerce(ELArithmetic.java:186)
        at org.apache.el.lang.ELArithmetic.coerce(ELArithmetic.java:357)
        at org.apache.el.lang.ELArithmetic.add(ELArithmetic.java:235)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstPlus.getValue(AstPlus.java:40)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstPlus.getValue(AstPlus.java:38)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:935)
        at org.apache.jsp.config.configDetail_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f5(configDetail_jsp.java:509)
        at org.apache.jsp.config.configDetail_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(configDetail_jsp.java:475)
        at org.apache.jsp.config.configDetail_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(configDetail_jsp.java:407)
        at org.apache.jsp.config.configDetail_jsp.access$4(configDetail_jsp.java:384)
        at org.apache.jsp.config.configDetail_jsp$Helper.invoke1(configDetail_jsp.java:615)
        at org.apache.jsp.config.configDetail_jsp$Helper.invoke(configDetail_jsp.java:679)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
<c:forEach items="${configForm.unselectedServers}" var="item">
  <c:set var="name" value="" />
  <c:forEach items="${item.configs}" var="conf">
    <c:set var="name" value="${name}, ${conf.name}" />
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Please see the error that this code gives in my edited question. Do you know why?

Comment: Updated the code to use a fn:join instead.  I am not sure if you can simply concat Strings with '+'.  Also, you may need to remove the empty set on the second line.  It may be doing something funny.

Answer (score 2):

Better approach is to handle it with JSTL itself as shown below:

```
<c:forEach items="${configForm.unselectedServers}" var="item">
  <c:set var="name" value="" />
  <c:forEach items="$item.configs" var="conf">
    <c:set var="name" value='${name + "," + conf.name}'/>
    <%--Do something here--%>
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

But if the question is just for your awareness you, can do something like this with scriptlet:

```
    <c:forEach items="${configForm.unselectedServers}" var="item">
      <c:set var="name" value="" />
      <c:forEach items="$item.configs" var="conf">
        <c:set var="name" value='${name + "," + conf.name}'/>
        <%
          String name = pageContext.getAttribute("name");
          //do something here
        %>
      </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Please see the error that this code gives in my edited question. Do you know why?

Comment: ` <c:forEach items="$item.configs" var="conf">` missing {} in item.configs

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps.

```
<c:forEach items="${configForm.unselectedServers}" var="item">
   <c:set var="name" value=""/>
   <c:forEach items="${item.configs}" var="conf">
      // here u can use yr variable like this
      <c:set var="name" value="${conf.first_name}"/>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Please see the error that this code gives in my edited question. Do you know why?

Comment: ` <c:forEach items="$item.configs" var="conf">` missing {} in item.configs